# preferences are not saving on usingcompound EditTextPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, dialog-preference

I have followed this tutorial for using compound [dialogpreference](http://alexfu.tumblr.com/post/23683149440/android-dev-custom-dialogpreference)

All stuff is working well only the issue is preferences are not saving for the app.
May be the system is not saving the preferences by default so is there any way to save them.

I have implementd `callChangeListener()` method for saving preferences:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    switch (which) {
    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
        mText = mEditText.getText().toString();
        Log.e("**CompoundEditTextPref line 63**",mText);
        callChangeListener(mText);
        break;
    }
    super.onClick(dialog, which);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the method `persistString(String value)`.
To retrieve value use `getPersistedString (String defaultReturnValue)`.

Take a look at [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#persistString%28java.lang.String%29).

Hope it helps.